# perform mysqli prepared stmt SELECT * FROM table to get all rows without bind_params, is possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

i'm moving to mysqli using prepared statements and i'm trying to get all rows from a table using this sql:

`$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(" SELECT *  FROM users ")`

the question is that i think don't need bind params because i don't need just few fields, i need all data so i really need this line?

`$stmt->bind_params("s", what goes here if i don't need just one value and want get all?);`

I need all the rows i don't see the need for bind any param so, how can i get the results like the old way?

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo $result['first_name'].'<br>';
 echo $result['last_name'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You need to bind params only if you have a where clasue with ? inside.

Comment: no need for `->bind_param()`, you have nothing to bind anyway. or just use `$mysqli->query()`, then just fetch

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to do that and i will share to you as my own response:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(" SELECT * FROM users")) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id_user, $first_name, $last_name, $other_fields_in_same_table_position);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo 'Row: '.$id_user.' - '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'<br>';
    }

    $stmt->close();

}else{

    echo "Error";
}
```